# GWT How to ensure the function has completely executed before reloading the page

Tags: java, html, gwt

I have a page which is implemented by GWT,now I want to refresh the page after user click "Submit" button and before finishing executing a service function "SubmitTargets"which is for calling process to execute Linux command like below code showed:

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source instanceof Button) {

            Button button = (Button) source;
                 if (button == submit){

                    iscsiInfo.process = IscsiInfo.Process.SubmitTargets;

                    Window.Location.refresh();

}
```

But the refresh method always execute before finishing executing the previous "SubmitTargets", have any idea how to refresh the page after completely executing the service function? Thanks!

Comment: `iscsiInfo.process = IscsiInfo.Process.SubmitTargets;`  Nothing calling here. It just a initialization statement.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. IT calls the method in the bottom of if else, that's why it execute refresh page first. Thanks!